# How to integrate asana with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, asana

I want to add Asana to my intellij IDE.

Right now I am using the web client, however it would be easier to work directly through the IDE.

I read the intellij help pages and they directed me to go to settings - tasks and fill in the details.
However, when i fill in the details, and click "test"

[image]

It says the test failed - unauthorized. I tried looking for help on the Asana blog, but found nothing.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Huh! I'm one of the few Asana engineers who doesn't use IntelliJ, but I'll ask around and see what other people do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What are you putting in "Username" and "Password"? It *should* require your API key (which you can find from "Account Settings" in the lower left > "Apps" tab > "API Key" link at bottom) as the username and no password (the API key fulfills the purpose of identifying and authorizing you).

Comment: None of the help documentation does not say that! As soon as i did what you said, it worked ;) Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped! Can you include a link to the documentation you were looking at? It might be possible to send a pull request (or even just a tweet or email) to get that updated so other people don't fall into the same trap :-)

Comment: This is what i was reading: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/enabling-integration-with-an-issue-tracking-system.html
The confusing part was that it is asking for "username". Had it stated "API Key" instead of the word username field, i would have known to paste it there myself. Because I read the Asana documentation, and that said i needed an API key to send a CURL request. And I found the API Key, but didn't know what to do with it, in Intellij.
So the change imo should be -> remove password field, and rename "username" to "API Key", which will make it self explanatory.

Comment: Also, I would suggest, on the asana side, add to your documentation how to integrate with different IDE's, it is very easy to use it, after i set it up

Comment: I am following the exact same steps as you suggest @agnoster, however, I keep getting the an error "Request failed with HTTP error:NOt Found" . I have a screenshot as well, attaching in a separate answer as I dont think comments allow pictures

Comment: This method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

Everything you need in March 2020 is:

1. Go to "My Profile Settings" -> "Apps" -> "Manage Developer Apps"
   [image]
2. Click "New access token" and create a new token. Give it a name, like "Task Server" and note it down (it's shown only once!)
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. Done for now in Asana. Open the IDE and open "Preferences" -> "Tools" -> "Tasks". Increase the connection timeout:
   [image]
4. Go to the "Preferences" -> "Tools" -> "Tasks" -> "Servers" and add new "Asana [G]" server. Open the "Server configuration" tab and click "Manage Template Variables". Add a `workspace` variable. Check "Show on first tab" for convenience:
   [image]
5. Click "Ok" and change "Tasks List URL" to `{serverUrl}/tasks?workspace={workspace}&assignee=me`:
   [image]
6. Change `id` and `singleTask-id` properties in "Server Configuration" to `gid` and `data.gid`:
   [image]
7. Finally, go to the "General" tab and fill in the details.
   [image]

`Username` is your access token.
`Project ID` and `Workspace` can be taken from URL of project's home and workspace's home.
Read more about the REST API in [the docs](https://developers.asana.com/docs).

Comment: This is pretty great and works well! 

One thing of note that I got hung up on for a while, the API does not support filtering by both assignee and project, so if you want to only retrieve tasks from a particular project you'll have to replace the "Task List URL:" with `{serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks`.

Comment: Getting a 404 Not Found

Comment: See Mat Lipe's comment above for 404 issues.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR; You're probably missing the Project ID field (if you're already putting your api key in for the username)

I ran into the Request Failed: Not Found error as well.  According to the asana api (when I tried the request via curl) to list tasks you:

```
"Must specify exactly one of project, tag, or assignee + workspace"
```

The intellij task / asana integration is set up to list tasks from a project. You need to fill in the Project ID field in the intellij IDE Task Server Configuration  > General.
You may need to query the api to get your project id:

```
curl -u <api_key>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects
```

Adding the Project ID to your settings should fix the task requests.

---

**Pro Tip ™**

Personally I want to list all tasks assigned to me across all projects. You can customize the intellij task server settings to ask for all tasks in a workspace.
To do this go to the "Sever Configuration" Tab on the intellij Task Server Configuration, click on manage "Manage Template Variables..." button and a variable for workspace_ID and provide your workspace id.
You can get your workspace IDs here:

```
curl -u <api_key>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces
```

You also need to change the Task List URL in the settings to:

```
{serverUrl}/tasks?workspace={workspace_ID}&assignee=me
```

Comment: Regarding the Project Id.
When I open Asana on the relevant project, the url contain your project id:
https://app.asana.com/0/[Project_ID]/list

Answer (score 3):

Update August 2018 (at least, if you're using Asana's workspaces):

1. Under `Server Configuration`, click the button to `Manage Template Variables`.
2. Add a new template variable named `workspace_ID`, and check the box to `show on first tab` (ignore the `serverURL` value I've put in here, I was messing around):[image: Template Variables]

   3. For the value of `workspace_ID`, get the number from a cURL request (substituting your own API key):

      curl -u '0/987654321fedcba': https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces
   4. Save the changes.
   5. There's been a change to Asana's API : you can specify [assignee + workspace] or you can specify [project]; you can't specify [ project + assignee ].
   6. Still in `Server Configuration`, change the `Tasks List URL` to one of the following (depending on what you want) :

      ```
      {serverUrl}/projects/{project_ID}/tasks
      ```

      or

      ```
      {serverUrl}/workspaces/{workspace_ID}/tasks?assignee=me
      ```
   7. Press the `Test` button and you should be OK.

Comment: NOTE: As of IntelliJ 2019.3, if you are using the workspaces URL, you need to uncheck the project_ID under "Show on first tab". If you don't do this, IntelliJ will think the form is incomplete and not load your tasks (even though the connection test passes).

Comment: Thanks @Hudon. In 'Server Configuration', I also had to replace all occurrences of `id` with `gid` (i.e. `{id: "gid", "singleTask-id": "data.gid"`} ).

Answer (score 1):

I am following the exact same steps as you suggest @agnoster, however, I keep getting the an error "Request failed with HTTP error:NOt Found" . I have a screenshot as well, as attached

[image]

Answer (score 1):

API Keys are deprecated in favour of OAuth 2.0.
See here: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth#api-key

Comment: How do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your Api key as username, leave password empty and check "Use HTTP Authentication"